# Pass 2 parameters to jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have this function:

```
function PostData(idTag, nameTag){
    $.post(".../info/act/set?params=" + idTag + nameTag,  function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })
}
```

In HTML i got this list with 2 inputs:

```
        <li><label>NAME: <input id="name"></input></label></li>
        <li><label>ID: <input id="ident"></input></label></li>
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass the input values(#name and #ident contents) to the PostData() function in order to submit data to the server.
I have tried this but when i check the logs it shows this: "params
:
"[object Object][object Object]"

```
function submitData() {
    var name = $("#name").text();
    var loc = $("#loc").text();

    val1=$("#name").val(name);
    val2=$("#loc").val(loc);

    PostData(val1, val2);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: kinda confused why you mix `$("#name").text()` and `$("#name").val()`. also add `var` before val1 and val2

Comment: what is the need of this ` val1=$("#name").val(name);
    val2=$("#loc").val(loc);` in here ?

Comment: initially i was thinking to get the text from the input and then send it as a value. I'm a beginner and now i realize is pretty nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues to address here. Firstly the HTML; `<input />` elements do not have a closing tag so that should be removed.

In your `submitData()` funciton you're getting the `text()` of the `input` elements, which will be empty, then setting that to their value, before attempting to pass *jQuery objects* to `PostData()`.

`PostData()` itself then seems to be expecting strings, not the jQuery objects that you are sending. It would also make sense to separate the values, either as a comma delimited string in a single parameter, or two separate parameters. Here is a full implementation of how to achieve the latter:

```js
function PostData(idTag, nameTag) {
  $.post('.../info/act/set?id=' + idTag + '&name=' + nameTag, function(data, status) {
    console.log(data, status);
  })
}

function submitData() {
  PostData($("#name").val(), $("#loc").val());
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label>
    NAME: <input id="name" />
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>
    ID: <input id="ident" />
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: this is working! thank you for your clear explanation

Answer (score 3):

Well if am not wrong you are trying to read data 
It will be like this

```
function submitData() {
    var val1=$("#name").val();
    var val2=$("#loc").val();
    PostData(val1, val2);
}
```